# How to fetch user details only once

Tags: react-query

I have several components that make use of user details.

Since user details don't change that often, I want to fetch them only once.

One way would be -

```js
const twentyFourHoursInMs = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
defaultOptions: {
    queries: {
      refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
      refetchOnmount: false,
      refetchOnReconnect: false,
      retry: false,
      staleTime: twentyFourHoursInMs,
    },
  },
})
```

Other way is to fetch data once in base component and use cached data in other components by using `queryClient.getQueryData('user')`

Which way would be better?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`queryClient.getQueryData('user')` is not a good way to access data in component, because it doesn't create a subscription like `useQuery` does. Even if you set a high staleTime, you might want to manually invalidate the query.

One example would be on a user details page, where the user changes their name. After making the mutation, you'd likely want to invalidate the user details query, or update the data from the mutation response with `queryClient.setQueryData`.

In those cases, you would want your components that depend on the user details query to re-render with the new data, and for that, you need `useQuery`.

---

if you want a true "only once" fetching, you'd need:

```
staleTime: Infinity
cacheTime: Infinity
```

- by setting `staleTime`, you define how long a resource is considered as fresh. As long as it is fresh, data will come from the cache only.
- By setting a higher `cacheTime`, you avoid that the query is garbage collected. Per default, if you unmount all the components that have an observer (via useQuery), the query is considered as inactive and will then be garbage collected after 15 minutes. That's another reason to prefer `useQuery` - because it creates an observer that keeps your query active.
- You *do not* need to turn off the `refetchOn...` flags. React Query will only do those smart refetches on certain events *if* the data is stale - which is never if you set infinity staleTime.

Comment: Should this still work in v4? It's not working for me.

Comment: yes, nothing changed in this regard.

Comment: Thanks @TkDodo, my issue was the API was returning a 500 so it kept sending the request.

Comment: Only for complete, even more, this answer. You can pass this properties as options parameter, like this:

const { data, isLoading } = useQuery('cache-key', fetchData, {
    staleTime: Infinity,
    cacheTime: Infinity
  });