# Why is useQuery being called for every Observer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-query

### What I have

I'm using `onSuccess` callback of `useQuery` to validate if an API call returns data, if the response doesn't return data a toast with the message "no result found" is rendered.

### The problem

The toast is being rendered multiple times once for each observer, I know that this is the expected behavior since the hook is executed for each observer.

### What I want

I have searched some [resources](https://tkdodo.eu/blog/react-query-error-handling#the-global-callbacks) and although some of them mention that global callbacks can be used to avoid this behavior, it is not clear to me how I can filter the requests to show this toast only for some of them. what I mean is, if the query key of the request is equal to "search" and the response did not return results.

```js
const queryClient = new QueryClient({
  queryCache: new QueryCache({
    onSuccess: (error) =>
      // how to filter here the request to show the toast
      // according to the queryKey and if no data is retrieved from the backend
  }),
})
```

### Some other questions

1. there are other approaches to avoid this behavior(run code in every observer)?

### Update 1

I use axios as a client, how should I handle TS typing in error or success callbacks?

Comment: @DreamBold actually the ticket you sent is about react-apollo not react-query

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71282427/how-to-fetch-user-details-only-once

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you've got a FAIL condition masquerading as a SUCCESS condition. Something like your api returns a 200 response but no data.. In that case the right thing to do is NOT to handle the problem with an onSuccess handler, but rather to throw an error from your query function and let your onError handler manage it instead.
e.g.

```js
useQuery({
  queryKey,
  queryFn: async (..args) => {
     const response = await actualQueryFn(...args);
     if(!response.data) throw new Error("No Data");
     return response;
  }
});
```

The onError handler will receive the error and the query. From there you can introspect the query to figure out what message to show.

e.g.

```js
const queryClient = new QueryClient({
  queryCache: new QueryCache({
    onError: (error, query) => {
      // Do stuff with query and error to show the right toast message.
    }
  }),
})
```

Comment: sorry, I updated my question since the validation should be done in the `onSuccess` method, I think your answer also applies to the `onSuccess` method. What is not clear to me is how should I do the filtering, I have this queryKey: `['searches', 'list', params]`, how I should validate if no data is retrieved from the Backend `(data. length === 0)`? and the query key matches the mentioned queryKey? this is not clear to me taking into account that typescrip does not show me autocomplete since data does not have an assigned type.

Comment: I have updated my answer because I think you're asking the wrong question. You don't want to use onSuccess, you want to use onError. You just need to throw an error in the right place.